# how to pin the view/object at the relative same place on different iPhone size?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

Like the below picture shows, on different iPhone sizes (4", 4.7", 5.5"), the blue and red views are still at the same relative position, but still can scroll down to get more space to show more information, how to do it?

I'm confused on how to implement such with scroll view. Thanks very much for your help!
[image]

Comment: Using only this information you provided I suggest you to find out the height of current screen and calculate positions manually

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Azat, we can use "UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height" to get the different height based on different iPhone size at runtime, thus can dynamically layout our views in a relative fixed position. For the example at above question description:

1. put the red and blue views in the stack view, to make them as one entity
2. calculate the scene height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
3. calculate the top distance we need the stack view (that is combined red and blue views together) away from the top edge of the scene
4. let's assume, except the first app launch interface we can see, we want to scroll down to find more things, an additional orange view is added
5. and we want put the orange view just right below the scene, and its bottom is 20 points from the scrollview bottom edge
6. in the storyboard, pin the scrollView to the view edge, pin the stack and orange view leading and trailing to the view, pin the red, blue and orange view's height to 120 points(you can change the height you like)

For 1,2,3,4,5, we can write the code in a function and call it in viewDidLoad, like:

```
    func viewLayout() {
    let bottomMargin:CGFloat = 20.0
    let sceneHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let topDistance = sceneHeight - stackView.frame.height - bottomMargin
    let metric = ["topDistance": topDistance, "bottomMargin": 20.0]
    let views = ["stackView": stackView, "orangeView": orangeView]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-topDistance-[stackView]-bottomMargin-[orangeView]-bottomMargin-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metric, views: views))
    }
```

thus, whatever iPhone size you use, the stack view always layout at the bottom of scene with 20 points away from bottom, and you can scroll down to see the orange view.